# Accessing/Setting instance variables: Name is stored in String variable

Tags: java, string, object

There are several variables of a Java objects instance.

```
instance.blora
instance.sragen
instance.kudus
```

There are also Strings storing the names of these variables.

```
String str;
str.add("blora");
str.add("sragen");
str.add("kudus");
```

How can I set the values of the instance using `str[1]`, `str[2]`, and `str[3]`?
(Somehow like `instance.(str[0])`)

Comment: I guess you want to use map

Comment: @billz Later I might, but now I try to refactor some code iteratively and therefore like to keep the objects variable names.

Comment: @StefanBollmann how did you define instance here?

Comment: This is unclear. What you've written doesn't make sense. "str.add" : add method doesn't exist on "String". Can you explain more accurately what you're trying to do?